# How do I earn Diamond Trophies in the time-based daily/weekly challenges?

Tags: ps3, rayman-legends

I'm trying to get to the 11th Level of Awesomeness in *Rayman Legends*. No matter how hard I try, I can't seem to get higher than gold in the normal challenges and silver in the extreme challenges, which means its going to take me four to six months of daily effort. For the distance challenges, I just need to keep practicing. **I need help with the timed challenges.**

From looking at videos, it seems **there are ways of boosting that will increase my speed and ways of landing that keep my momentum**. But I can't seem to find any useful tutorials explanations for how to do this. **What moves do I need to learn in order to start challenging for Diamond Cups?**

For example, at about the 9 second mark in this videom, you can see the player's speed/momentum pick up, but I can't tell what he or she is doing to get up to that speed.

You can see the same speed-up around the 21 second mark of this video, but the player isn't able to maintain it for long.

The speedup happens almost immediately in this video:

Comment: Just some pointers: only try the Dojo on extreme challenges, because the normal ones allow co-op, which means you can be much faster on some levels. However, I think the Dojo is the easiest one to get diamond on in the extreme challenges, because you can perfect all the rooms individually, and can remember the times at each level end to get some feedback on how well you're doing. (I only ever got a single diamond and it was in a Dojo.) As for speed, if you jump during a dash-attack you keep the momentum. This is the most important trick. I suggest you watch some videos on youtube.

Comment: [Here is some info about moves that let you go faster.](http://steamcommunity.com/app/242550/discussions/0/864978109894182866/)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Oh, I've watched a *ton* of videos on YouTube. None of them tell me what buttons to push when. The closest is [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sy9SjQOpu_4), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically two techniques are used. The first technique you probably know where you attack while the sprint button is held down. The biggest speed boost occurs when you attack while running down the hill.

The second technique is when you hold the down button (or holding down on the stick) while jumping. You'll notice in the videos that the characters do a flip when they jump. You're seeing the second technique in action. The jump flipping technique essentially conserves/preserves momentum.

So if you time it right, and speed attack boost down a hill, jump soon after, while holding "down", continue jumping after, and avoiding obstacles while doing it, you can maintain a wicked speed. It takes some practice, but if you can master it, you'll be on your way to the top of the leaderboard in no time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to press your attack button to gain little speed boosts.  When you get better at this technique, you can press the button as soon as the previous animation ends and keep your speed consistently up.  Also, if you attack and then immediately jump, you go even faster, but this technique is significantly more difficult because you must make sure that you are not jumping at the wrong places.  One other note, do not use the attack speed boost up inclines because this will actually reduce your speed.  It takes some practice, but once you get the technique down, your times will drastically improve.